# How to JSON.stringify object from URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this code which grabs all the input type from a form

```
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  const data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form).entries());
```

My question is how to JSON.stringify the above `data` object? I need to stringify so that I can pass it through JQuery ajax to post the data.

If I loop it, it will print out below

```
for (let p of data) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample of data structure if you `console.log(data);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this achieve what you are looking for? The data is an array of arrays because Object.entries has been called on it. The Object.fromEntries() method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object. After it's back to being an object, call JSON.stringify().

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(data);
const stringifyObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
```